# Multifunction custom JS file in karate 1.4.1

Tags: javascript, testing, karate

I am in the process to upgrade the karate version from 0.9.6 to 1.4.1 and could see following issues,

1. Multifunction javaScript file isn't supported
2. Common functions needed to be added as inline function in feature file or create single function JS file [even after creating single fun JS file it is being read as string]

currently mentioning the functions in feature file as below is working

```
* def random_string =
"""
    function(length){
        let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
    }
"""

* def random_number =
"""
    function(length){
        return Math.floor(Math.pow(10,length-1) + Math.random() * (Math.pow(10, length) - Math.pow(10, length-1)-1));
    }
"""

* def random_value_from_list =
"""
    function(str){
        let arr = str.split('|');
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        return arr[random];
    }
"""
```

Looking to achieve
config.js file

```
var upperCase = function (str) {
  if(str == null){
    return null;
  }
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

var randomUuid = function (length) {
  var UUID = Java.type('java.util.UUID');
  var UTILS = Java.type('karate.utils.Utils');
  var uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

  var value = UTILS.stripHyphens(uuid.toString());
  if (length) {
    value = value.substring(0, length);
  }
  return value;
}
```

in feature file

```
Feature: Basic end-to-end testing
  Background:
   * call read('classpath:karate/utils/config.js')

 Scenario Outline: test
    Given def asserstion = {  "result": "SUCCESS", paymentpath: "#present" }
    And def reqid = "KARATE_ID1_"+randomUuid()
    And print reqid
```

```
- classpath:karate/scenarios/testcases/test.feature:12
* call read('classpath:karate/utils/config.js')
js failed:
>>>>
01: read('classpath:karate/utils/config.js')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
>>>>
01: (var randomUuid = function (length) {
02:   var UUID = Java.type('java.util.UUID');
03:   var UTILS = Java.type('karate.utils.Utils');
04:   var uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
05: 
06:   var value = UTILS.stripHyphens(uuid.toString());
07:   if (length) {
08:     value = value.substring(0, length);
09:   }
10:   return value;
11: })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:1 Expected an operand but found var
(var randomUuid = function (length) {
 ^
Unnamed:10:2 Invalid return statement
  return value;
  ^
Unnamed:11:0 Expected eof but found }
})
^

- org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:425)
- com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.evalForValue(JsEngine.java:169)
- com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:165)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1286)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:59)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:124)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

I am reaching out to find out
"Is there anyway we can incorporate JS file with common functions used across the tests."

PS. Apologies if I have missed in anything while reading the upgrade docs but isn't the newer version is suppose to simply and work towards having clean code rather causing redundancy.

Comment: see if this comment addresses your question on re-use of JS within JS: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2329#issuecomment-1671156706 - there has been a LOT of work on the embedded JS engine that you can find using the above thread as a starting point. the recommended approach for re-usable code is to use Java static methods or this approach in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file - if you have strong opinions on how things should be, please contribute code or reach out for enterprise support